# How to calculate a sum of specific documents using aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a schema representing a message thread. So each document in the mongo database looks something like:

```
{
    id: "thread_id",
    participants: ["user1", "user2"],
    unReadMessageCounts: [
         {
             participant: "user1",
             count: 5
         },
         {
             participant: "user2",
             count: 3
         }
}
```

**What I want to do is get a sum of all unread messages counts for a given user - say, "user2"**. I know I could do this by just doing a `find()` on the collection and then writing a function to sum up to counts for a given user. But I'd like to use mongo's `aggregate` functionality if possible. I know I can do a `match` to first select all threads in which "user2" is a participant, but then how do I construct the `group` and/or `sum` expressions to pull out the right field from the document?

Comment: Fair point. In my case the number of documents to begin with is not terribly large so the slight increased brevity of @chridam answer made it preferable for me. But I also upvoted your answer since it is indeed a perfectly sound solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following aggregation pipeline to get the desired result. The initial step filters out the incoming documents to only accept `"user2"` participant by way of the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator.

The preceding pipeline stage then "denormalizes" the `unReadMessageCounts` array through the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator that outputs 2 documents from the array for each incumbent document (in your above sample data).

Further filtering is necessary to aggregate data for the correct participant and this is done through another **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline step.

The final aggregation operation using **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** specifies a group `_id` of `null`, calculating the total counts for all documents in the pipeline using the accumulator operator **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** on the `"unReadMessageCounts.count"` field.

So, running this aggregation pipeline on the sample data given:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "unReadMessageCounts.participant": "user2" }
    },
    { "$unwind" : "$unReadMessageCounts" },
    {
        "$match": { "unReadMessageCounts.participant": "user2" }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total": { "$sum": "$unReadMessageCounts.count"  }
        }
    }
])
```

will yield the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "total" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: While this solved the problem it's not the way to go because of the size of the documents to process after the first `$unwind` and as you know this can be a very big problem if you are dealing with large collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator to as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032549/3100115) to limit the size of documents to process in the pipeline then you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) your documents and in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage you use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator to return total of unread message for "user2".

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "unReadMessageCounts": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "participant": "user2" }
        }
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$or": [
                { "$eq": [ "$participant", "user2" ] }, 
                { "$not" : "$participant" } 
            ]}, 
            "$$DESCEND", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ]
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$unReadMessageCounts" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "total": { "$sum": "$unReadMessageCounts.count" }
    }}
])
```